# Roadway and book recommendations to math study.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, reference-request, education

I had some calculus, linear algebra and complex analysis courses back in college. But it is not comprehensive. And I felt that my college math was not taught in a logical sequence (maybe because my major is engineering). And some of the confusing theories may  be better appreciated if taught in more detail and in a more logical sense.

Now I had some time and not pushed by so many exams. I'd like to re-study the mathematics by myself. This is all about interest and curiosity. And I believe I can figure out all my confusions so far. But I need some guidance.

So could you guys recommend some books and logical study sequence for me? My target is as below:

- (1) To fully understand the integral transform, such as fourier, laplace
  and wavelet transform.
- (2) To fully understand some *strange* fuctions, such as [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), etc.
- (3) To fully understand the [Euler formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): e^ix = cos(x) + i sin(x)
- (4) To fully understand the complex number "i" and complex analysis.
- (5) To fully understand the differential equation.
- (6) To get a thorough understanding of modern algebra.
- (7) To help my work in computer science.
- (8) To get the general idea of modern mathematics.

Really appreciate your advice!

Comment: Might wanna start with [this](http://interruptions.net/literature/Wicklund-BASP81.pdf).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber It's an interesting article at the first glance. I need some more time to read it. Thanks.

Comment: This a paradigmatic overly broad question.

Comment: @Potato I listed my specific targets as a hint just to make the question not too abroad.

Comment: @smwikipedia Each one of these targets should be its own question!

Comment: @AlexanderGruber While the article in the paper is an interesting piece of research could you please elaborate on what it has to do with the question? The question seems to be of the sort "I would like to understand A, B and C. My background is X. Could you please give me help on how to understand A, B and C, given my background" and I can't work out how an article on self-definition pertains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should like to point out from the beginning that several parts in your question are unclear and in some sense unanswerable (such as 'the differential equation' because there is no such thing as 'the' differential equation). Also it is unclear to me how deep you want to go into these topics so that I restrict myself to what I consider to be to the minimum. I suggest:

(1) start with Stein's Complex analysis (Princeton lectures in analysis, vol. II), chapter 1 (this will answer part 2 and 3 of your question, apart from the complex analysis part, for which you also have to look at least at chapters 2-4).

(2) Part 1 of your question will be answered by Stein's Fourier analysis (same series, vol. I), chap. 5 and 6. The fourier transform comes up in increasing level of sophistication in Stein's series, such as in chap. 2 of vol. II and chap. 5. of vol. III. A good reference for integral transforms is Antimirov's applied integral transforms, chap. 2.

(3) Part 5: the basic material can be found in Arnold's ODE text chap. 1-4 (several sections could be omitted). But of course one could endlessly read about differential equations; differential equations come up also in several place of Stein's series (so I suggest you get these books, they are relatively expensive but they are excellent in any aspect, and also suitably elementary).

(4) Part 2: frankly speaking there is no such thing as the Dirac delta function, the road leads to distribution theory, which is dealt with in chapter 3 of Stein's functional analysis (vol. IV of the series). If you want to know something about special (gamma, zeta, elliptic and theta) functions, a good place to look is Stein's complex analysis, chap. 6-7, 9-10.

(5) Part 6: Lang's algebra book (GTM), as much as you can, at any rate chapters 1-6 (mainly group, ring, module and field/galois theory).

(6) Part 7-8: This is difficult to answer, but the more mathematics you understand the better your thinking. As far as 8 is concerned, Gower's Princeton companion to mathematics gives you a good overview of what mathematics is about. But again this is a very broad question; however if you get to know some category theory (Mac Lane's book), you will certainly understand many ideas underlying the algebra parts of mathematics.

By the way there is not much to be said about Euler's formula, some people find it special but it is in fact a triviality.

Comment: As a comment, I thought that this exactly what the OP is looking for; there is not much sense in just naming some standard books, as this certainly won't help much. Stein's series (which I possess and am well acquainted with) presupposes only a very elementary background (and this is also stated in the preface), which you seem to have. By the way a bit of general topology can't hurt you, such as chap. 1-4 in the book of Munkres. Of course it also always nice to have several books on the same topic, because different books take different point of views. As I said, this is just the minimum.

Comment: @ooo I re-labeled my questions with numbers for clarity. And thank you so much! I will start with the Stein's series. (Sorry I didn't know about Stein before.)

Comment: No offense btw, why Euler's formula is trivial? Some say it is interesting because it involves "i", "e", "power function" and "trigonometric functions". I don't fully understand it because it quite deviates from the *classic meaning* of "power function".

Comment: Well it trivial is because it is immediate from the definitions of the trigonometric functions, and it much easier to understand than your other topics. By the way something which is very nice about the Stein series is that he proves some nontrivial theorems in elementary number theory, such as Dirichlet's theorem, the prime number theorem and the Hardy-Ramanujan estimate for the partition number.

Comment: I would argue that the formula has non-trivial implications, for example in computing $\pi_1(\mathbb{Z})$...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be interested primarily in Analysis. Perhaps something like Stein and Shakarachi's Analysis sequence would be suitable? I haven't read their book, but it seems like Fourier analysis plays a central role in their development.

For a thorough understanding of the basic techniques in Modern Algebra, Aluffi has what I think is a very readable textbook.

Another good series is Lee's three books on Manifolds.

This is already a tremendous amount of reading, by the way - especially if you haven't done pure math for a while. You may want to narrow your interests a little bit.

Comment: same question, any recommended sequence?

Comment: I would read the Analysis and Algebra books first and concurrently. Lee's series will need some Algebra, and I think topology is harder to understand without a thorough understanding of basic analysis. I don't know what prerequisites the Analysis series requires, but my impression is that it is self-contained. Check the introduction.

Answer (score -1):

Functional Analysis - Kreyszig

Methods of Mathematical Physics- Courant & Hilbert or Arfken

Complex Analysis - Stein & Shakarchi or Rudin or Ahlfors

Differential Equations - G.F. Simmons

Algebra- Herstein and thereafter Lang/ Hungerford/ Jacobson

Concrete Mathematics - Ronald L. Graham, Knuth, Patashnik

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Human knowledge are gathered mostly as experience. The latter ones seem  to be more generalized and complete. Is there any specific sequence to read these materials?

Comment: These are mostly independent. I would recommend that you have a look at them, and read their prefaces to get an idea of what these books deal with and what are the prerequisites.